# How to create a custom Google Maps on a site?

Tags: google-maps

for the new company site, they want a textbox that has an address, once the person clicks search a google map should appear with lots of points on that area. These points are places pre-defined in a database.
Is there any way I can implement this? A great example of this is on laterooms.com:

http://www.laterooms.com/en/k16296355_manchester-hotels.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is a mashup between simple geocoding (example available here):

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

And places (example available here)

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

you will find quite some good infos on this page here: see the examples and see what you can do with the code

https://developers.google.com/maps/